# SQL Constraint from a reference table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, foreign-keys, constraints, alter

I am building a table for a front end users to use - and would love to alleviate as much error making as possible.

User enters 4 fields, a season from a drop down, and then pick the fiscal year its associated with also in a drop down. (The other two are dates entered by the user).

Both drop down values come from the same place same system table. `t_season` What I would like to do is once the user selects season lets say `16-17 events` what I would like to happen is that `fyear` gets pulled from the data, similar to a trigger but as a constraint.

I've got a constraint to set up/audit create dates - and I would like to build a constraint similar to a create date I have set up on the table.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[LTR_PERF_DATES] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_LTR_PERF_DATES_create_dt_1__13]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [create_dt]
```

but I'm not sure what to do ... something along the lines of

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[LTR_PERF_DATES] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_LTR_PERF_DATES_fyear]  DEFAULT _____ FOR fyear
```

something like this maybe:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[LTR_PERF_DATES] ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_LTR_PERF_DATES_fyear] FOREIGN KEY [ID] REFERENCES [dbo].[tr_season] ([fyear])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try 
SELECT YEAR(GETDATE())
will provide the current year as an integer.

Comment: we can't use this formula - because its not quite a year field we've got. we have a season field and fyear field neither of them are dates. Any other ideas.